# How to create a vector from 1:n in C++ (Armadillo)?

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo

Such a simple question but I haven't found an answer in the armadillo's documentation.

I'm looking for the Armadillo/C++ equivalent to Matlab's `x = (1:n)` where `n` is a number and `x` is thus a vector `[1, 2, 3..., n-1, n]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please, pay attention to [this](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#linspace) function.

```
vec v = linspace<vec>(1, N);
```

Generates a vector starting at 1 and ending at N. It does just what you need.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much--missed it when I was perusing the documentation. Much appreciated!

Comment: I will. Have to wait 3 mins before the site will let me :)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here. Please at least mention the function name and maybe give an example how to use it to get the desired result.

Comment: @liori OK, sorry. Just a second.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't seem to be correct. This could work `vec v = linspace<vec>(1, N, N);` or better if we replace `vec` with `uvec`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that c++11 is acceptable and you are using `std::vector`, you can use `std::iota`:

```
std::vector<int> x(n);
std::iota(x.begin(), x.end(), 1);
```